# Aplicação ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails4

Existe a possibilidade de alterar o estado de uma aplicação rails, de produção para teste ? com a possibilidade de voltar para produção novamente

Answer (score 1):

O correto seria você parar a aplicação e depois iniciar ela já no ambiente de teste, não seria uma boa prática.

Answer (score 1):

Sim.

```
RAILS_ENV=<ambiente> <comando>
```

Por exemplo, para rodar o *seeding* do banco de dados de teste, faça:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails db:seed
```

Os ambientes são `test`, `development`, `staging` e `production`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode rodar o comando abaixo:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails s
```

ou

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```